# Showing that $(\frac{\sin3A}{\sin A})^2 - (\frac{\cos3A}{\cos A})^2 = 8\cos2A$

Tags: trigonometry

> Show that $$\left(\frac{\sin3A}{\sin A}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\cos3A}{cosA}\right)^2=8\cos2A$$

**Solution**

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\sin3A}{\sin A}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\cos3A}{\cos A}\right)^2
&=\left(\frac{\sin3A}{\sin A}+\frac{\cos3A}{\cos A}\right)\left(\frac{\sin3A}{\sin A}-\frac{\cos3A}{\cos A}\right) \\[4pt]
&=\left(\frac{\sin3A\cos A+\sin A\cos3A}{\sin A\cos A}\right)\left(\frac{\sin3A\cos A-\sin A\cos3A}{\sin A\cos A}\right) \\[4pt]
&=\left(\frac{\sin(3A+A)}{\sin A\cos A}\right)\left(\frac{\sin(3A-A)}{\sin A\cos A}\right) \\[4pt]
&=\left(\frac{\sin4A}{\sin A\cos A}\right)\left(\frac{\sin2A}{\sin A\cos A}\right)
\end{align}$$

What do I do next?

The textbook from which the above question is taken hasn't introduced the double angle formulas yet. So I am trying to find a way to do this question without using the double angle formulas.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Next time, whatever you typed into the Codecogs LaTeX equation editor, type that between dollar signs.

Comment: Use $\sin 2A = 2\sin A \cos A$ to expand $\sin 4A$, and then cancel the remaining factors of $\sin 2A$.

Comment: The textbook from which the above question is taken hasn't introduced the double angle formulas yet. So I am trying to find a way to do this question without using the double angle formulas.

Comment: You have already used a generalization of the double angle formula!:  $\sin(A+B) = \sin A \cos B + \sin B \cos A$, haven't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$,$$\frac{\sin4A}{\sin A\cos A}\frac{\sin 2A}{\sin A\cos A}=\frac{2\sin 4A}{\sin 2A}2=4\cos2A\cdot2=8\cos2A.$$

Comment: The textbook from which the above question is taken hasn't introduced the double angle formulas yet. So I am trying to find a way to do this question without using the double angle formulas.

Comment: @mku You didn't mind using the compound angle formulae. The double angle formulae are just special cases.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using triple angle formula  assuming $\sin A\cos A\ne0$ we get

$$(3-4\sin^2A)^2-(4\cos^2A-3)^2$$

$$=24(\cos^2A-\sin^2A)-16(\cos^4A-\sin^4A)$$

$$=8(\cos^2A-\sin^2A)(3-2(\cos^2A+\sin^2A))=?$$